# How can I create a model/UML in Eclipse easily?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, uml, eclipse-emf-ecore

I'm trying to create a diagram for several packages and about 30 classes of code. I need to be able to show how it all connects and works together. I've looked into eUML2 but supposedly it won't work with my OS (Mac OS X 10.6.8). Thus, I'm not trying to manually create one using Ecore but this is taking forever. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks. (FYI the code is Java).

Comment: have you tried ANDROMDA, a tool available on sourceforge.net

Comment: Do you have a link? I can't seem to find anything relevant.

Comment: sourceforge.net/projects/andromda

Comment: Other questions that seem to address this same issue [Good Free UML Tool for Java Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse) and [Eclipse UML Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988384/eclipse-uml-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse your code with an UML tool.

I know that Omondo is working well with Mac OS because one of my team mate is using it and he can reverse multiple packages in order to create a single UML model but it is not free. We can also mix PC and Mac while working on the same model. Really cool :-)